# URIs for linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic

Tags: apt

I'm using Ubuntu desktop (Linux version 3.11.0-15-generic (buildd@allspice)). I tried to get linux source code by command:

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic
```

Then I saw this error:

```
home@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get source linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

I can't find the suitable URI link to add in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I have Kubuntu, not vanilla Ubuntu, so I don't know how to do this via GUI, but some entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` have an additional "source" entry. e.g. `deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main` is on one line, followed by `deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main`. I think the latter is required to download sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image: Software sources]

Enable "Source code" checkbox on tab "Ubuntu Software". Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to get sources lists.

Comment: Thanks Danatela. I did as your instruction and it could download linux source code. But instead of downloading linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic, it downloaded linux 3.2.0-60.91.

Comment: home@ubuntu:/tmp$ sudo apt-get source linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic'