# Error :: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install PIL a python module on ubuntu

I first need to install a package called python-imaging using the following command

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

When I try and do this I get the error

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436247/uris-for-linux-image-3-11-0-15-generic) question whihc shows how to fix via the GUI but I'm using the command line. Does anyone know how I can fix this error..?

UPDATE:
Based on the below answers I've updated my package list but I now get this error. Not sure if it is related, if not I'll start a new question as I can't find reference to the error anywhere.

```
E: Build-Depends dependency for python-imaging cannot be satisfied because candidate version of package python-all-dev can't satisfy version requirements
```

Comment: The first error message is quite confusing. It shows up although there are SOME sources in the file while the message implies that there are no sources at all. What the message tries to say is you have to ADD a source that contains the info.

Comment: after adding `deb-src` lines in `sources.list` I had to `apt update`  to get this message to go away

Answer (score 211):

**`software-properties-gtk` option "Source code"**

I recommend this for the desktop:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

then under the "Ubuntu Software" tab click "Source code":

[image]

This has added some `deb-src` lines under `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and now I can do `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`.

I've couldn't find a clean CLI method so I create this bug report for it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1802718

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

**CLI method**

I recommend this for Docker images:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list~
sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Tested on the Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image. After this change, I can successfully do for example:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep hello
```

and before the change it failed with the error:

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Previously mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1011675/52975 go and upvote that answer.

Note however that the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contains lines such as:

```
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

which means that the above `sed` would enable sources but not non-sources for some types of repos. I don't think that it  matters much though.

Comment: This just worked for me with **ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: Also solved it for me on *Ubuntu 18.04*

Comment: how is the accepted answer "I know you asked no GUI but sometimes devs just don't support it properly" - this is not helpful when you have no GUI (e.g., Docker).

Comment: @kilgoretrout "how is the accepted answer" Because Google search hits beat exact question semantics.

Comment: working in 19.04

Comment: working in 20.04

Comment: @LouisMaddox I think I also had to do it on 20.04 and it worked but maybe it's a carry over from previous install. If you're uber serious about debugging this, one option is to try to reproduce on 20.04 on a clean QEMU install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792 Let me know if you find something out.

Comment: Apologies, it began to work, deleted my comment. It made an entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list` whereas from the comments here I was expecting it to be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (I am on Linux Mint which perhaps handles these differently from Ubuntu, but this forum is strictly Ubuntu only)

Answer (score 60):

You can edit the source list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) directly. I think you need to add in/uncomment these lines:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

I worked this out by disabling the source code option, and saving one copy of the sources.list file, then enabling the source code option, saving another copy, then running `diff` on both.

You may want to change the prefix `http://gb.` to the prefix of the other sources in your list (so it uses your nearest repo mirror), and you can also ignore the `#Added by software-properties`.

After editing `sources.list`, run `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install again.

The full `diff` can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7780959/)

---

Another way is to generate a new one. One method to get a complete sources.list is to use this site:https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: "After editing sources.list, run sudo apt-get update before trying to install again." -- That was the key, thanks!

Comment: sudo sed -i -e 's/# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: thanks pal for remember me that `$ sudo apt update`

Comment: @Vincent's comment was enough for me and super clean

Answer (score 32):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then remove `#` or add lines with `deb-src $url`, for example:

```
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
```

Or copy from the existing lines, e.g.

```
deb blah blah
deb-src exact same blah blah
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine for additional information.

Comment: exec `sudo apt-get update` after editing the `sources.list` file

Answer (score 18):

Here is the command line solution

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep deb-src  #  see what will get changed
```

typical output of above cmd

```
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

if you are good changing above lines, which is always true on a fresh ubuntu install, then issue :

```
sudo sed -i~orig -e 's/# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

which does a backup of input file, then a search for commented out deb-src where it removes the comment to make those lines active ... following refresh of local metadata will give your machine awareness of new catagories of ubuntu packages

```
sudo apt-get update  #  refresh of local metadata
```

now issue once again your original command which failed with :

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Comment: You can skip the cp and use `-i~orig` with sed to have sed make the backup.

Comment: This is my favorite answer because it shows what will be changed first, then command line to do the change.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 16.04, I successfully made these updates to sources.list :

```
$ sudo diff /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bkp 

6c6
< deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
---
> # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

19c19
< deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
---
> # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe

39c9
< deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
---
> # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

53c53
< deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
---
> # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 4):

In Linux Mint (I am on version 18) you can go to **Software Sources** (search for it in the start menu or open it from a terminal with `software-sources`). There, on the first tab, you will find a checkbox **Enable source code repositories**. If you enable this the program will put the correct lines into your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list` file. Just don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` (or hit *Update the cache* in the Software Sources) after that.

Answer (score 3):

My solution takes the already configured deb lines and adds them as deb-src ones.
Tested using the perl:5.28 docker image which builds upon buildpack-deps:buster which builds upon debian:buster:

```
sudo su -
grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list | perl -pe 's/deb /deb-src /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: This is great as it works in Debian docker images. Initially I thought that using perl might be an overkill but it seems perl is already included in the docker image so it's fine.
The `sed` equivalent would be almost identical: `grep '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list | sed -e 's/^deb /deb-src /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Remove “#” from all lines starting with `deb-src` from the `/etc/apt/sources.list` but create a backup first. Then update.

Just run these commands:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list~
sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```