# Adding Source URIs

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am attempting to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep glfw3
```

However, I'm recieving this error in return:

```
reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

I looked at the advice here: [Error :: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list)

but I'm not sure if I should use the same method as advised by the top comment, or where to to put those lines in /etc/apt/sources.list if I did.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project) are the steps I'm following to install GLFW3, essentially

```
1.) Downloaded latest build here: http://www.glfw.org/download.html
2.) Run: sudo apt-get build-dep glfw or sudo apt-get build-dep glfw3 *(stuck on this step)*
3.) run: make, then make install
```

http://www.glfw.org/download.html
Any help is appreciated.

Running Ubuntu desktop 16.04

edit:

Also once I have this installed, does anyone know if it will be available globally, or do I need to add it to shell somehow?

Comment: Please edit your post to include : 1) Ubuntu version, 2) The version of  `glfw3`  that you want to build ... http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=glfw3&searchon=sourcenames

Comment: @KnudLarsen updated, included the guide I was using to install as well. I'm not 100% which version I need, but I assume the latest. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You could look in the "Software sources" utility (it's in the dash, or in the software center menu), and enable all the "Source" repositories. This should be the easiest way.

Comment: @JonasCz it seems that may have actually worked, you should post that as a comment so I can give you a check. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to enable the "Source" repositories in the "Software sources" or "Software and updates"  utility, which can be found in the dash, or under the "Tools" menu in the software center.

In the Software source utility, on the "Ubuntu software" tab, enable the "Sources" checkbox:

[image: screenshot]

This should be enough in order to allow you to get the source & compile. If it's not, enable the "source" repositories in the "Other software" tab too.

> Also once I have this installed, does anyone know if it will be available globally, or do I need to add it to shell somehow?

It should be available globally, without having to do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the "latest" version of `glfw3` → "Ubuntu 16.10 yakkety" has (currently)  glfw3-3.2-4 .

Add a line to /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb-src [url] yakkety universe main
```

... and run 1) `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get build-dep glfw3` 2) `sudo apt-get install fakeroot`

Getting the source and building the packages is one command: `cd /home/name/[new-folder]` ; → → `apt-get -b source glfw3=3.2-4` ( No sudo, please.)