# Vim 8 with system clipboard on 16.04 LTS

Tags: vim, clipboard

I have install Vim 8 (so that I can use [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale)). Unfortunately I can't seem to get the system clipboard to work. (E.g. using `vim-gnome` I would use the `"+y` to yank to the system clipboard. Has anybody got this working?

I installed Vim 8 using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

Comment: This version of vim is compiled without clipboard support. You can see that with `vim --version | grep clipboard` and see it comes up as `-clipboard` instead of `+clipboard`. I don't know of any prebuilt vim 8 packages for ubuntu 16 that have clipboard.

Comment: @MattGreer that's odd. I use the `jonathanf/vim` PPA on 16.04, and I have `+clipboard`. OP: What does `update-alternatives --display vim` report? Is it pointing to `vim.gtk3`?

Comment: @muru apologies I may have conflated a couple of issues. I'm pretty sure when I posted this I was actually using elementary os. In between then and posting my answer, I switched to 17.10 and encountered a similar problem. That's when I ended up building from source. It's entirely possible that this is not actually an issue on 16.04, but I don't currently have a machine with that installed to check on this further.

Comment: @muru your comment prompted me to look a little more and you are right. If after adding the `jonathanf/vim` PPA you `apt install vim`, it installs `vim.basic`. If you instead `apt install vim-gtk3`, then you get vim.gtk3 which has `+clipboard`

Comment: @jerome what Matt says^: the `vim` package's `vim.basic` has lots of features disabled (on Debian/Ubuntu and on PPAs which build on the existing packaging) - it's just a few steps above the `vim.tiny` installed by default. You should install one of the GUI Vims or `vim-nox` for more features (but `vim-nox` understandably has clipboard support disabled). This is true of all versions of Ubuntu and Debian, though the GUI Vim packages may have different names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If after adding the `jonathanf/vim` PPA you `apt install vim`, it installs `vim.basic`. If you instead `apt install vim-gtk3`, then you get `vim.gtk3` which has `+clipboard`, and thus the system clipboard. Regardless of which one you install, it will get symlinked to `/usr/bin/vim`

(converted my comment to an answer in case anyone else stumbles into here)

Comment: I can confirm that installing `vim-gtk3` using `jonathanf/vim` repo works just fine, and is more straightforward than building from source. Changing the above to the accepted answer.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious comment, but it's worth noting this is still a regular terminal Vim and not GVim, even though the 'g' in gtk might mislead you.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get what I needed by building from the source with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove vim # to remove the binary I had installed
$ sudo apt build-dep vim
$ git clone git@github.com:vim/vim.git
$ cd vim/src
$ ./configure --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-cscope \
            --prefix=/usr \
            --enable-gui=auto --enable-gtk2-check --with-x # this is what I needed
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: If anybody gets stuck with the error on `sudo apt build-dep vim` **You must put source URLs in your sources.list file**, this  [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/857433/690231) would be helpful!

Comment: Also, using `--with-python3-config-dir=$(python3-config --configdir)`, is better since it gives the config directory searching by itself, even if you are using **miniconda/anaconda** for `python`. Also, using `sudo checkinstall` instead of `make` should be better as it leads to ease in uninstallation!