# Access to system clipboard with vim 8.1.2269 on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vim, clipboard, vimrc

I work with `vim` on Ubuntu 20.04 installed from the official repositories:

```
$ apt policy vim
vim:
  Installed: 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the `.vimrc` file I have the following config:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

That integrated the `vim` clipboard with the system, i.e. `y` in Normal mode would send the highlighted text to a `vim` record and also the system clipboard. Until yesterday. After running the upgrades `vim` no longer interacts with the system clipboard.

This could happen if some GUI package had been removed or disabled by the upgrade ([clipboard integration is provided by such packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005205/vim-8-with-system-clipboard-on-16-04-lts)). But those packages are still around and healthy:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep vim
ii  vim                                           2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
ii  vim-common                                    2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 all          Vi IMproved - Common files
ii  vim-gtk                                       2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 all          Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor (dummy package)
ii  vim-gtk3                                      2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GTK3 GUI
ii  vim-gui-common                                2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 all          Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
ii  vim-runtime                                   2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 all          Vi IMproved - Runtime files
ii  vim-tiny                                      2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5                                 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

And the confirm the clipboard extensions are installed:

```
$ vim --version | grep clip
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do you use terminal Vim or Gvim? Can you please confirm that `"+yy` works, so that it is clear that the problem is only with the `unnamedplus` setting, or to confirm that the problem is with the clipboard interaction?

Comment: I use `vim` on the terminal. The `y` are copying text to the internal register, but not to the system clipboard.