# How to download source of the latest stable Ubuntu's kernel via Apt?

Tags: apt, kernel, 18.10

So far I did the following:

1. I've commented out `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (related [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/496549/78223)).
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`.

Now I'm trying to obtain the current kernel sources as [Ubuntu's wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel):

```
$ sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux-signed' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.18.0-13-generic'
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-signed_4.18.0-13.14.dsc'
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-signed_4.18.0-13.14.tar.xz'
Need to get 0 B of source archives.
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in linux-signed-4.18.0

$ sudo apt-get source linux-source
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux-meta' as source package instead of 'linux-source'
NOTICE: 'linux-meta' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+git/cosmic
Please use:
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+git/cosmic
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-meta_4.18.0.13.14.dsc'
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-meta_4.18.0.13.14.tar.xz'
Need to get 0 B of source archives.
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in linux-meta-4.18.0.13.14

$ ls /usr/src
linux-headers-4.18.0-12  linux-headers-4.18.0-12-generic  linux-headers-4.18.0-13  linux-headers-4.18.0-13-generic
```

But it doesn't download anything.

Running `apt-get clean package_name` command before `source`, doesn't help either.

What I'm missing?

Comment: You are not at all following the instructions of the link you posted...

Comment: @fkraiem I'm trying to obtain the sources, not build, so I don't need to follow all the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache search linux-source
linux-source - Linux kernel source with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-4.4.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.4.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-4.10.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.10.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-4.11.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.11.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-4.13.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.13.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-4.15.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.15.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-4.8.0 - Linux kernel source for version 4.8.0 with Ubuntu patches
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -L linux-source-4.13.0 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-4.13.0
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-4.13.0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-4.13.0/copyright
/usr/src
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/linux-source-4.13.0.tar.bz2
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian/debian.env
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian/tests-build
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian/tests-build/README

   <...snip...>  

/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian.hwe/control.stub.in
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian.hwe/modprobe.d
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian.hwe/modprobe.d/common.conf
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0/debian.hwe/copyright
/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0.tar.bz2
```

Notice the last entry `/usr/src/linux-source-4.13.0.tar.bz2` is a `bzip`-compressed `tar` archive that contains the source.

Your version numbers may vary.

Comment: I had to run `apt-get source linux-source-x.yy.z` before it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [feedback](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107535/78223), this is the right command to download the current kernel sources into `/usr/src`:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

Here are the commands to extract the source files:

```
cd /usr/src/linux-source-$(uname -r | cut -f1 -d-)
sudo tar jxvf linux-source-*.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get source` downloads the source package to the current directory, not to `/usr/src`.

Moreover, since the current directory is typically writable by you, `apt-get source` need not, and therefore should not, be run with `sudo`.

Comment: Ok, I missed that, I was expecting in `/usr/src`, on the other hand the files are just config files (in `linux-signed-4.18.0/`), I was expecting Linux sources which I can edit and compile, so I didn't expect that. Will review the steps again, as they're confusing. Not as they normally should be in a standard Linux. Thanks.